# Calling on-premise OAuth API through Azure Application Proxy

Tags: azure, oauth, bearer-token

I have a on-premise API that use OAuth, so I use the "Authorization:Bearer ..." header when calling it from on-prem.  Now I want to call this API from external using Azure Application Proxy with authentication.  I know how to acquire a Bearer Token to authenticate against the Application Proxy.

The problem is that in the same HTTP Call to the on-prem API from external, I need to have 2 different "Authorization:Bearer ..." headers, one for the Application Proxy and one for the on-prem API.

I cannot just have 2 Authorization headers, right?  So how do I call my on-prem API from external?

---

Edit :  I've never found the real solution so I built an "On-Premise Proxy" that swap Authorization:Bearer after the Azure App Proxy.  Here's how it works :

1. The outside app inserts 2 headers with the call to Azure App Proxy (AAP). First is Authorization:Bearer with the token required by AAP.  The second is a dummy header "AuthorizationOnPrem" with the token that is required by the app behind the Azure Proxy (on-prem).
2. The Azure Proxy redirect the call to my custom "On-Premise Proxy".
3. This On-Prem Proxy copy the token from AuthorizationOnPrem to Authorization.
4. Then the On-Prem Proxy call the real on-prem app with the same data that it got called but with the right token.

I know it's quite patched but it worked for me with the on-prem app I needed.  And it was surprisingly easy to do.  Might not scale well though.

Comment: Running into the same issue right now. It is infuriating that the Application Proxy expects the token in the Authorization header instead of the Proxy-Authorization header. I don't know how they could have neglected the use case of needing Authorization for something behind the proxy.